# How to unmarshall XML via Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, unmarshalling

Okay, assuming some XML like:

```
<Result>
 <Value>
  <Foo>1</Foo>
  <Bar>1</Bar>
 </Value>
 <OK>true</OK>
</Result>
```

And some classes:

```
class ResultValue
{
  public int foo;
  public int bar;

  public ResultValue() {}
}

class Result
{
  public bool ok;
  public ResultValue value;

  public Result() {}
}
```

how do I create/populate a Result object *including* its value member?

I got as far as

```
from x in source.Elements()
where ((int)x.Element("Value").Element("Foo") == 1)
select new Result()
{
    ok = (bool) x.Element("OK"), // ok, I understand as far as this!
    // what goes here, to fill .value?
};
```

I'd really appreciate you explaining not only what code I need, but "why", because I find the syntax "a bit" confusing :-P (actually, if you can point me to a decent primer on this, it would be a great help, I can't find anything that covers anything more basic than a flat structure).

Comment: This is called deserializing, not unmarshalling.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [xml serialisation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx)? May be better suited to your needs